# cannot tee the result of the shell command within python script

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to run the shell command which tees the output to some file within python script but when I see the log file of tee output it's empty. The code looks like this:

```
val_home =  os.environ["xyz"]
pwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(val_home)
os.chdir("..")
avk_home = os.environ["abc"]
del os.environ['abc']
command = "source %s/somefile/ %s/inputparamater | tee config.log" %(val_home,val_home)
execute(command)#function written to execute shell command ,no issue with this
assert search_string("config.log","Success") ,"Target config failed"
rm_file(['config.log'])
os.environ["AVKRUN_HOME"] = avk_home
os.chdir(pwd)
```

The file `config.out` is empty but when I run the command manually I see the tee file output.

Comment: Remove the trailing slash in `source %s/somefile/`

Comment: How is your `execute()` function implemented? Does it handle pipes?

Comment: Since the point of the whole script is to run a few unix commands, why dont you write a shell script instead of Python one?

Comment: def execute(command,inp = None):  #execute looks like
    """
    Execute UNIX command and return the exit status
    """
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    result = list(process.communicate(inp))
    result[0] = bytes.decode(result[0]).split("\n")
    result[1] = bytes.decode(result[1])
    result.append(subprocess.getstatusoutput(command)[0])
    return subprocess.getstatusoutput(command)[0]
    #return result

Comment: Its just a part of the script ,the script has something else do ....